# Detect touchesMoved over different view than touchesBegan

Tags: ios, swift

I am working on a iOS app with Swift that contains a view that contains a grid of `UIImageView` elements. Basically what I am trying to do is enable a sort of "drag over and highlight multiple elements" ability where, for example, the user can start by touching one of the `UIImageView` elements and without lifting his/her finger, can drag over others in a line/diagonally/etc.

Each of the `UIImageView` elements that are "touched/swiped over" this way are changed slightly, either by applying a highlight or some other indication that it is "selected."

Another way to imagine what I am trying to do is to imaging a word search puzzle, where I can touch a specific letter and then drag over multiple letters to highlight a word that I think I have found. As I am dragging over each letter (each being a different `View` of its own), they are highlighted to show my current selected group of characters.

I have tried implementing something like this using `touchesMoved` and `touchesBegan`, but those only seem to work on the original `View` that they were called from. If I begin touching one `View` and then drag over to another, that other `View`s `touchesBegan/Moved` is never called.

Is there an easier way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

TLDR : override `touchesBegan`/`touchesMoved`/`touchesEnded` on the parent, not on the children.

One way to do this is to override the `touchesBegan`/`touchesMoved`/`touchesEnded` callbacks on your view controller. Basically check the position of the touch agains the frames of the image views. Something like this should do it:

```
     import UIKit

     class ViewController: UIViewController {

     // this array holds the UIImageViews
     private var imageViews:[UIImageView] = []

     override func viewDidLoad() {
         super.viewDidLoad()
         // here i just created randomly placed image views
         for _ in 0...9 {
             // create random image views
             let iv = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "random-image"))
             // random positions
             iv.frame.origin.x = CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(200))
             iv.frame.origin.y = CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(400))
             // add to controller's view
             self.view.addSubview(iv)
             // store in array for later reference
             imageViews.append(iv)
         }
     }

     override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent)
     {
         self.highlightImageViews(touches)
         super.touchesBegan(touches, withEvent: event)
     }

     override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent){
         self.highlightImageViews(touches)
         super.touchesMoved(touches, withEvent: event)
     }

     override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent)
     {
         // do something with the highlighted image views in the imageViewsArray
         super.touchesEnded(touches, withEvent: event)
     }

     func highlightImageViews(touches: Set<NSObject>){
        if let touch = touches.first as? UITouch {
            for iv in imageViews {
                let point = touch.locationInView(self.view)
                if (CGRectContainsPoint(iv.frame, point)) {
                    iv.alpha = 0.5
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```